# Create event Google calendar error

Tags: php, cmd, google-calendar-api

I am a beginning programmer and new to google calendar API.
I want to create an event using the code given by google to create one, the problem is that i can only get a list of my upcoming events but I can't create an event.

This code works: https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/php

I putted this code under the other one:

```
$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
  'summary' => 'Google I/O 2015',
  'location' => '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
  'description' => 'A chance to hear more about Google\'s developer products.',
  'start' => array(
    'dateTime' => '2018-08-28T09:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone' => 'Europe/Brussels',
  ),
  'end' => array(
    'dateTime' => '2018-08-28T17:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone' => 'Europe/Brussels',
  ),
  'recurrence' => array(
    'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'
  ),
  'attendees' => array(
    array('email' => 'stefanos.stoikos@gmail.com'),
    array('email' => 'stefanos.stoikos@gmail.com'),
  ),
  'reminders' => array(
    'useDefault' => FALSE,
    'overrides' => array(
      array('method' => 'email', 'minutes' => 24 * 60),
      array('method' => 'popup', 'minutes' => 10),
    ),
  ),
));
$calendarId = 'primary';
$event = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event);
printf('Event created: %s\n', $event->htmlLink);
```

when i execute this in cmd i get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message '{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
    "message": "Insufficient Permission"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Insufficient Permission"
 }
}
' in C:\xampp\htdocs\StefanosProject\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Http\REST.php:118
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\StefanosProject\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Http\REST.php(94): Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...')
#1 [internal function]: Google_Http_REST::doExecute(Object(GuzzleHttp\Client), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...')
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\StefanosProject\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Task\Runner.php(176): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\StefanosProject\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Http\REST.php(58): Google_Task_Runner->run()
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\StefanosProject\vendor\google\apiclient\src in C:\xampp\htdocs\StefanosProject\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Http\REST.php on line 118
```

I tried different solutions to create an event but i keep having errors, can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what's happening. The PHP Quickstart that you cited uses a `read-only` scope - `CALENDAR_READONLY`. But, what you're trying to do requires a write scope because you're trying to [create events](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert). Hence, change your scope to 
`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar` or whatever is the counterpart in PHP language.

Upon changing, don't forget to delete your previously saved credentials for the new scope to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely your create event code is correct, but you need to configure oauth for the user you're adding events to:

https://developers.google.com/calendar/create-events

Specifically check out this part here:

```
In order to successfully create events, you need to:

* set your OAuth scope to https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.
ensure the authenticated user has write access to the calendar 
* with the calendarId you provided (for example by calling calendarList.get() for the calendarId and checking the accessRole).
```

Heres a longer tutorial that includes setting up and using oauth:
http://usefulangle.com/post/29/google-calendar-api-create-event-php